# I have many different products on my website how can I get them to display under specific categories?

Tags: categories

How and where do I put code to get products assigned to categories. I bulk imported categories after I already had products setup. Now I was wondering how I can move all the different products to the proper categories without having to do it one by one if possible.

Comment: What are products? What information do you have to base category assignment on?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a pretty good inbuilt bulk editing system. Just select all the products/post for each category and select bulk edit from the menu where you'd normally see more to trash.

Comment: I am trying to bulk edit products when I select several items and hit edit it loads the page but then closes itself like I never hit the edit button in the 1st place. Do you know why it wont stay on page so I can edit?